# How to control a program's default stack settings in BSD or Linux?

Tags: linux, stack, freebsd, memory-model

Let's say I have a running program, and I look at **/proc/[pid]/map** in BSD (or **/proc/[pid]/maps** in linux), I'll see a line like:

```
0xbfbe0000 0xbfc00000 3 0 0xc74c4198 rwx 1 0 0x3000 COW NNC default - CH 1001
```

which is the stack.  All my PC-BSD programs use this same stack boundary 0xbfc00000.  On linux, with ASLR turned off, a similar thing happens.

I would like to play with these settings on some programs, but the stack doesn't even seem to be specified in the elf program headers or section headers.

So if I want to change the settings, such as:

- change execute permission of the stack
- set the stack boundary to another value

Is there a way to change the "stack setting" for an individual program?
How about system wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FreeBSD:

On amd64, i386 and powerpc you can control wether the stack is executable with the sysctls `kern.elf32.nxstack` and `kern.elf64.nxstack` (since FreeBSD 9.0).

You can use `limits(1)` to start a program with a different stack *size*, or use `login.conf(5)` to set the limits for different classes of users. The stack *boundary* looks hard-coded in the kernel. See the field `sv_usrstack` of the `struct sysentvec` for your architecture.

**Edit**
Your program can request a larger maximum stack size by using `setrlimit(2)`.

The GNU linker supports a `--stack` option, but according to the manual page;

> This option is specific to the i386 PE targeted port
>              of the linker

So this only works on windows.

Comment: I've noticed some programs have a GNU_STACK piece in the ELF data.  I wonder if there is some way to also set the boundary this way.  Otherwise it seems really strange that the ELF info can specify the memory layout of everything _execpt_ the stack.

Comment: The elf format contains information about which parts of the program are to be loaded into memory and where. It does _not_ set resource limits, because that is controlled by the OS. See `setrlimit(2)`